# I have an Video as base64/bytes encoded data (in memory, not a file), how to pass base64 data directly to moviepy VideoClip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, io, moviepy

I have an Video as base64/bytes encoded data (in memory, not a file), how to pass base64 data directly to moviepy ImageClip instead of a file?

I Use the `imageio.imread` it do not work.
I Also Used the `imageio.mimread` it also do not work.
I Also Used the `io.BytesIO` it also Do not Work.

I do not want to save the video in the file and reopen it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a [example]?